# How to get string literal line numbers in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, abstract-syntax-tree

I've got a function that finds all docstrings in classes, functions, and methods but I'm currently struggling to find a solution to get all the docstrings that are not in either of these three options. Is there a way of using ast (or any other method) to get the line numbers of loose docstrings?

Example file I would be checking to find all docstring line numbers -

```
a = '\ttesting this file!'
b = "abc"
print a

def trigger():
    a = b'\r\n'
    b = "\t"


"""                     <---- I want these line numbers
dasdas                  <---- I want these line numbers
adasdsa                 <---- I want these line numbers
"""                     <---- I want these line numbers

class A:
    """                       Function correctly picks up all docstring lines below
    dsadasd
    dsadas
    """
    def new():
        """
        dsadas
        :return:
```

Here is my current function -

```
 def get_all_docstring_positions(self, file):
        """
        this method will return all docstring positions in functions, classes & methods.

        :param file: file to iterate through
        :return: list of positions
        """
        lines_to_skip = []

        os.getcwd(), os.listdir(os.getcwd())
        root = ast.parse(open(file).read())

        # Functions
        for node in ast.walk(root):
            if isinstance(node, ast.FunctionDef):
                if self.node_status(node):
                    lines_to_skip.append(list(range(node.lineno + 1, node.body[0].value.lineno + 1)))
            elif isinstance(node, ast.ClassDef):
                # Classes
                if self.node_status(node):
                    lines_to_skip.append(list(range(node.lineno + 1, node.body[0].value.lineno + 1)))
                for class_ in node.body:
                    if isinstance(class_, ast.FunctionDef):
                        for n in class_.body:
                            # Methods
                            if isinstance(n, ast.FunctionDef):
                                if self.node_status(n):
                                    lines_to_skip.append(list(range(n.lineno + 1, n.body[0].value.lineno + 1)))

        # SORTING ONLY FOR UNIT TESTING, THIS SORT WILL NOT BE NEEDED
        return sorted(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(lines_to_skip)))

    def node_status(self, node):
        """
        reduced duplication

        :param node: node to check against
        :return: boolean
        """
        if node.body and isinstance(node.body[0], ast.Expr) and isinstance(node.body[0].value, ast.Str):
            return True
        return False
```

For the example file above, `get_all_docstring_positions` would return `[15, 16, 17, 18, 20, 21, 22, 23]`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that by definition these floating strings are not docstrings: ["A docstring is a string literal that occurs as the first statement in a module, function, class, or method definition."](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/). It seems you are looking for a) a string literal, b) not assigned to a value or used in an expression, and c) at the top level scope of a module, is that correct?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Yes that is correct.